Using a regexp function to bring back the number immediately after specific words and needs to stop matching once it comes across non digit character
The regexp function needs to stop matching once it comes across a non-digit character, but it continues to match and doesn't stop
tried this:
regexp_replace(substr(CASE_CMT,instr(CASE_CMT,'FINAL CLAIM COUNT',1,1),29), '[^0-9]', '')

expected this comment: "final claim count: 2 AAA 12345"
to return:  "2"
instead, it returned this:  "212345"

Thank you.  I have changed the sql server tag to show oracle

instr(CASE_CMT,'FINAL CLAIM COUNT',1,1) will not match final claim count: 2 AAA 12345 because you are searching for an upper-case string when the data is lower-case.

Don't try to remove the non-digit characters. Look for the digit characters following the prefix:
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         CASE_CMT,
         'FINAL CLAIM COUNT:\s*(\d+)',
         1,   -- Start from the 1st character
         1,   -- Look for the 1st match
         'i', -- Case insensitive
         1    -- Return the 1st capturing group
       ) AS digits
FROM   table_name;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (case_cmt) AS
SELECT 'final claim count: 2 AAA 12345' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



DIGITS




2



fiddle

Now the only issue is with inconsistent comments.  For example, one may write "Final claim count - 1 aaa" which the code then returns a blank for that claim count since it is not written exactly like "Final claim count: 1 ".

@TannerTolbert Then search for [ :-]* between the terms (or whatever else is appropriate to your requirements) rather than :\s*.

Thank you so much. That worked, and my issue is fixed!
